# How to use different Hive metastore for saveAsTable?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I am using Spark SQL (Spark 1.6.1) using PySpark and I have a requirement of loading a table from one Hive metastore and writing the result of the dataframe into a different Hive metastore.

I am wondering how can I use two different metastores for one spark SQL script?

Here is my script looks like.

```
# Hive metastore 1
sc1 = SparkContext()
hiveContext1 = HiveContext(sc1)
hiveContext1.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "tmp/Metastore1")

#Hive metastore 2
sc2 = SparkContext()
hiveContext2 = HiveContext(sc2)
hiveContext2.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "tmp/Metastore2")

#Reading from a table presnt in metastore1
df_extract = hiveContext1.sql("select * from emp where emp_id =1")

# Need to write the result into a different dataframe
df_extract.saveAsTable('targetdbname.target_table',mode='append',path='maprfs:///abc/datapath...')
```

Answer (score 1):

HotelsDotCom have developed an application (WaggleDance) specifically for this https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/waggle-dance. Using it as a proxy you should be able to achieve what your trying to do

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It is not possible to use one Hive metastore (for some tables) and another (for other tables).

Since Spark SQL supports a single Hive metastore (in a [SharedState](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SharedState.scala#L47)) regardless of the number of `SparkSessions` reading from and writing to different Hive metastores is technically impossible.